# When is it worth to make postgresql database replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

My application processes 0.5MLN of records per day and this number will be increasing. It use postgreSQL database. I consider to make replica of my database, the replica would be for reading only. I wonder whether it will speed up reading data service if the replica will use for reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can spread you read load, then it will definitely help. I have such a setup in production for years. I works like this:
I have a master, that is processing all the writes, and some very specially crafted reads.
The rest of the reads, that are slow, and can tolerate the replication latency is served from the replica.
So far we only need one replica, but it's possible to set up a pool of replicas, and spread the read load among them.

The simplest way for spreading the load would be to use something external, that gives the client the replicas in  a round-robin fashion. ([DNS Round Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) comes first into my mind.)

Comment: Could You tell more about the reasons for this in your case?

Comment: Yes, the reason for us was to have a hot standby backup. The load splitting was only secondary. We have a write heavy load, so offloading as much as we could from the master improved performance. Also, most of our read loads was of the reporting kind, where a daily batch job would do, but with very slow queries. Also the replication latecy did not count there, as the batch was cut based on timestamp, so we simply delayed running it until the data from the next day started to come in.

Comment: A bit of additional information: our write load is around 20 MLN of records per day.